# RaspberryPi debian wheezy: Run X application from a C program

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to do write a program that will help read text and pdf documents in C using open source programs on the raspberry pi.

the program is simple, nothing complicated.....

I am connecting to the raspberry pi through ssh from  my laptop...X forwarding is working ok because I can launch X applications from the command line without any issues.

I am using apache2 on the raspberry pi and I have made a user interface for this program where you can paste text, upload text files or pdf files.

The text is converted to speech with espeak which saves the output to a wave file.

Now the problem is I use:

`system("xmms2  play file.wav &")` in the C code ........just a short description

it compiles.....when i try it from the web page it displays errors:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
cannot start xmms2d.....failed to start xmms2 server
```

i even tried another audio player called aqualung and it worked once but the next day when I restart computer, it doesn't work anymore.

i google around and done everything from `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to making sure hostname on the client and host is not localhost but no success

So I think maybe there is something i did not add in the C program, maybe a header file that needs to be added or something like that.....Gtk+ is installed on my raspberry....

Or maybe i should not do it as a C program but do everything in bash or php....

if I use aplay to play the wav file, i get sound output, the only difference i that i need something with command line and user interface. so I can send commands from the program and also the user can pause and play the file whenever he wants.

Pls some advice is needed.... here is the code

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>   


char readcmd(void) //reading from text file /home/pi/cmdrdy.txt first character is read
{    //whenever text is received a 1 is written to this file, 2 for file received
    FILE *stream;
    int ch;
    if( (stream = fopen("/home/pi/txtrdy.txt", "r")) == NULL )
        return 0;
    ch = fgetc( stream );
    fclose( stream );
    return (ch-'0');
}


void  reset()
{
    FILE *ft;
    char ch;
    ft = fopen( "/home/pi/cmdrdy.txt", "w" );
    ch = '0';
    fprintf(ft, "%c", ch );
    fclose(ft);
}


void checktxt(){
    if(readcmd() == 1)
    {
        system("espeak -v en -f /home/pi/book.txt -w /home/pi/text.wav &");
        reset();  //to reset the text received flag to 0
        system("xmms2 play /home/pi/text.wav &");
    }

    if(readcmd2() == 2)
    {
        system("pdftotext -layout  /home/pi/upload/*.pdf  /home/pi/converted.txt &");
        delay(300);
        system("espeak -v en -f /home/pi/converted.txt -w /home/pi/book.wav &");
        delay(500);

        system("sudo rm /home/pi/converted.txt");
        system("sudo rm  /home/pi/upload/*.pdf");
        system("xmm2 play /home/pi/book.wav &");
    }
}

void main(){
    while(1){
        checktxt();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xauth

Comment: I have suggested an answer. I am curious to know whether this is correct, would you awfully mind telling me whether this solves your problem?

Comment: you should have put your edit as an answer if it addressed and fixed your problem. The question now looks muddled.

Comment: No, it is not a matter of starting at boot, it is a matter of running under root environment. The MIT magic cookie that allows control of the screen belongs to you, not to root, thus the XAUTHORITY shell variable is not set. The solution is still the same, you must give the owner of the C program the permit to write to localhost:10.0

Comment: please do you know how I'm to go about this, what file is localhost:10.0 referring to is /dev/stdout? this is a symlink to /proc/self/fd/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not run into this problem myself, but I can venture to form an educated guess as to why this is happening: from the look of it, it appears xauth does not extend to the child process. In fact, I was unable to locate XAUTHORITY in the output of

```
   export -p
```

on a Raspberry running Raspian.

I was unable to establish for sure, by Googling around, that this is indeed the case even for other OSes, but it is so easy to try and fix this, that it is worth a try anyway. I suggest you substitute the command with an executable script, call it /home/my_name/bin/my_script, made executable by means of `chmod 755` of course, in which you place the following 3 lines of code:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   export XAUTHORITY=/home/my_name/.Xauthority
   xmms2 play file.wav &
```

Since the `system` call first forks, then starts an instance of the shell with the caller environment variables, your program knows (and proves it knows) that your display is `10.0`, but access to it must be granted within the subshell in which the command `xmms2` is executed. This modification ensures you of this.

Comment: IT WORKS! Men IT WORKS!, thank you very much....going to improve the code a little now.....

Comment: xmms2 doesnt work so I've used uqualung

Comment: i have however discovered that it is because the C program handling everything is started at boot, it gets root privileges and this causes problems....when it has to launch an application that needs the display

Comment: @user280026 BTW, great song, Aqualung my friend, don't you start away uneasy, you poor old sod you know it's only me... Jethro Tull

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the above code a little bit now and added the advice into it

## include

## include

## include

## include

typedef enum {WAIT, TEXT, PDF, DOC}STATES;
typedef char STATE;
STATE current_state;

char readcmd() //reading from text file /home/pi/cmdrdy.txt first character is read
    {
    FILE *stream;
    int ch;
    if( (stream = fopen("/home/pi/cmdrdy.txt", "r")) == NULL )
    return 0;
    ch =fgetc( stream );
    fclose( stream );
    return (ch-'0');
}

```
void  reset()
```

{
    FILE *ft;
        char ch;
        ft = fopen( "/home/pi/cmdrdy.txt", "w" );
        ch = '0';
        fprintf(ft, "%c", ch );
        fclose(ft);
}

```
char convtts() {  //convert text to speech
system("espeak -v en -f /home/pi/book.txt -w /home/pi/text.wav &");
return (0);
```

}

```
char pdf2txt(){   //convert pdf to text
 system("pdftotext -layout  /usr/lib/cgi-bin/upload/*.pdf /home/pi/converted.txt");
return (0);
```

}

```
char pdftts(){ //convert converted text to speech
  system("espeak -v en -f /home/pi/converted.txt -w /home/pi/book.wav &");
return(0);
```

}

```
void state_machine(void){   //creating a state machine

switch(current_state){


case WAIT:


    if(readcmd() == 1)
    {
    reset();
current_state  =  TEXT;
    }

if(readcmd() == 2)
    {
 reset();
    current_state  =  PDF;
}
break;


case TEXT:

convtts();
while(convtts()==1);

system("/home/pi/bin/text_script");

current_state = WAIT;
break;


case PDF:

pdf2txt();
while(pdf2txt()==1);

pdftts();
while(pdftts()==1);
system("/home/pi/bin/book_script");
system("sudo rm /usr/lib/cgi-bin/upload/*.pdf");
current_state = WAIT;
break;
```

}
}

```
void main(){

while(1){

state_machine();
```

}
}

And it works like charm......thanks a million